# Declare non column member in class used for table sqlite Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, class, windows-phone-8, sqlite

I am creating a WP8 application with sqlite database.
I have a json which is to be parsed and save in database. Now before saving there is some formatting to be done on some field. I wanted to use same class for parsing json and then save that data to sqlite Database. That is why i need some class properties/members which will be not column but just a class property.

But it seems like the class of which type the table is created in sqlite cannot have any other member then column member. All members are by default considered as column. In SQLCE we can apply [Column] attribute on a class member to declare it as a column, and a member without a [Column] attribute will be just a class member. But in sqlite i am not able to find any way for this.

Please confirm if there is any way or not.

If there is any workaround for this, other than creating another similar class for json parsing and then assign those values to class for creating table.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using [sqlite-net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) library, there is an `[Ignore]` attribute which you can apply for properties that shouldn't be inserted into database.